# Confused about Ubuntu packages updates

Tags: versions

1. When Ubuntu publishes a new release - say, for example, from 16.04 to 16.10 - do the applications automatically get updated?
   For example, if as a part of 16.04 it has application ABC at version 1.0, and as part of 16.10 it has the same application ABC but at version 2.0, does going through the upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 include replacing application ABC from version 1.0 to 2.0?
2. Does "Ubuntu Software" contain applications of the version that is part of the Ubuntu release that my system is using?
   For example, if I have 16.10 installed, will the applications in "Ubuntu Software" be at a version that is more current than the versions I'd see for them in "Ubuntu Software" if I were running 16.04 instead?
3. If I am primarily concerned with stability, I assume the best strategy to follow is to use the version of those applications that come with the release of Ubuntu that I am using; and, if there is some software I want and it is in "Ubuntu Software", I should obtain it from there.
   However, sometimes I see very large discrepancies between the most current version of an application, and the version of that application available from Ubuntu.
   For example, in 16.10 the version of Calibre is 2.6; in 17.04 it is 2.75.1; but the current version available is 3.6.
   So, my questions are: Does this significant lagging in versions provided by Ubuntu ever happen due to people simply not putting in the effort to ensure Ubuntu provides a version somewhat close to the current version?
   And if that is the case, how would I know that (so that I could possibly decide to uninstall the version provided by Ubuntu, and instead rely on the version and subsequent updates provided by the application's provider)?
   In other words, how would I know the problem is simply that the developer isn't "sending" updated versions of his application to Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: If you are concerned about stability why upgrade an LTS release to an unsupported EoL 16.10?

Comment: To Pilot6' question:  Just to be clear, I was only using the 16.04 to 16.10 upgrade as an example, not as something to advocate.

Comment: To David Foerster's comment:  Forgive me, I wasn't aware of the distinction you are making between a forum and a Q&A site, but I do understand your point now.  Now my turn to be picky (in a friendly vain):  I do not think my question is a duplicate.  I searched the site, found a number of questions asking *WHY* Ubuntu's versions are far behind current, but that is NOT what I was asking.  I didn't word things the best, but my main question in my mind was, How would I know when an application's version in Ubuntu is far behind *because the developer ceased maintaining it with Ubuntu*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The answer to the first part of your question is no they are not going to be updated automatically however if you decide to upgrade your 16.04 to 16.10 then yes, everything will be upgraded to the last version in 16.10.
2. Yes
3. That's not the case, it's all about stability, in fact developer are putting a lot of efforts to patch the bug and security issues without pulling the last version of software from upstream which is a really easier thing to do, because they don't want to sacrifice stability.

Also read this for more information:
 [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: You are wrong with p.1. Upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 will upgrade all apps.

Comment: Read the next sentence `For example, if as a part of 16.04 it has application ABC at version 1.0, and as part of 16.10 it has the same application ABC but at version 2.0, does going through the upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 include replacing application ABC from version 1.0 to 2.0?`. The correct answer is positive.

Comment: @Pilot6 My bad I read it a couple of times again, I'll update the answer ;)

Comment: @Pilot6 Updated, and thanks for pointing it out  ;)